# If I have already had a PhD in philosophy in a foreign country, can I get another PhD in theology in the US or religious studies?

Tags: phd, philosophy

I already have a PhD in philosophy from a foreign country. I studied political philosophy, but I became interested in Christianity and want to study more about it. Can I get another PhD in theology or religious studies in the US?

Comment: At the current time there is no hard limit on how many degrees one can accumulate. Have at it and best of luck in your endeavors!

Comment: You may educate yourself as you please. Doctorates are not rationed. If you are in doubt, simply ask the department where you wish to do your second doctorate.